# Match string pattern - Replacement via awk-gsub with another pattern

Tags: awk, replace, gsub

**AIM**

1. I want to be able to match a pattern in a string, this using its initial and final boundaries.
2. I further aim to replace the pattern with "ID=".

**STRING**

```
Class=Grainyhead.domain.factors;Family=CP2-related.factors;id=TFCP2.Ca9750.2.YY2017.HT-SE2;strand=+;seq=TTCTGGTTGGGACCAGGA;score=7.62921;pval=6.53e-05;Averageconservationscore=1.77
```

**DESIRED PATTERN OF THE STRING TO BE MATCHED WITH A COMMAND IN AWK**

*PATTERN*

```
Class=Grainyhead.domain.factors;Family=CP2-related.factors;id=
```

*COMMAND*

```
(/\Class=(.*);id=/)
```

*AWK-GSUB*

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub(/\Class=(.*);id=/), "ID=", $4) 1'}
```

I am not sure about the (.*) use !

I commonly employed it in R to select part of a string.

Can this be employed as well in awk-gsub filtering?

Comment: But which `gsub`? Ruby function gsub? Lua function gsub? R function gsub? AWK function gsub?

Comment: awk gsub  @Daweo

Comment: what `awk/gsub()` code have you tried? what do you need to do after you get a match ... replace the match? further parse the match (or the remainder of the field that didn't match)? insert some data? something else?

Comment: I will replace (via gsub) with another pattern. @markp-fuso

Comment: ok, so Arnaud's answer does that (use `gsub()` to replace the maching pattern), but you'll probably want to make a few tweaks ... `FS=OFS="\t"` and `gsub(<ptn_to_find>,<replacement>,$4)` and of course provide the actual replacement pattern; I suggest you update the actual question with all of the additional details you've been providing in comments (not everyone is going to spend the time reading through comments trying to piece together the bigger picture); also update the question with the expected result (after performing the desired replacement)

Comment: Regarding [I will replace (via gsub) with another pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299555/match-string-pattern-awk-function-gsub-syntax#comment122491372_69299555) - `gsub()` may be a bad choice for that depending on the value of that replacement "pattern". Along with everything else, [edit] your question to tell us what that is and include examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your separator appears like a '`;`' (not a tab).

To filter with "*start with a token*", use '`^`' (not `\`) at  the beginning of the regexp.

After first replace, select the columns with `$`*number*.

```sh
cat file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/^Class=(.*);id=/, "id="); print $1, $6}' > outputfile
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. Nevertheless, this is not my full file. My file is tab separated. As I specified in the title this is only the content of my column 4. The string I am trying to work on.  @ArnaudValmary

Comment: @Myke Don't post sample input/output that doesn't look like your real input/output. If your real input is different from the example you posted in significant ways such as not using the field separator shown in your example then edit your question to fix your example. Don't show us one thing and then write that your real input is something different because, as you can  tell from the 2 answers you have already, that is confusing for us (and others reading this in future) and makes our solutions less likely to solve your real problem - just make the layout of your example like your real data.

Comment: Dear Ed, since I am working on replacing column 4 string I specifically posted only the contempt of the column 4. Hope it is fine and understandable from the example title. Best